# Is it possible to create and get triggers (enter and exit) for polygon geofencing in iOS

Tags: ios, ios8, mkmapview, geofencing, clcircularregion

I want to create an app, where when user taps on mapview , it will create geofence for that locations(it could be circular , polygon or any type).
I want to get notify whenever user enters or exits from the created region.
I have managed to achieve with circular regions but want to do it with polygon or user defined area as well.

Please suggest.

Answer (score 0):

Use the CLLocationManager: create a region and monitor it with `startMonitoringForRegion:`. For notifications use the delegate methods

```
locationManager:didEnterRegion:
locationManager:didExitRegion:
locationManager:didDetermineState:forRegion:
```

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/CoreLocation/Reference/CLLocationManager_Class/index.html

Comment: But it's only possible with circular regions and not with polygon regions.